# Inject service in Doctrine Fixtures on PhpUnit context

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine, phpunit, fixtures

I'm using Symfony 4 and PhpUnit and i try to inject service in Doctrine Fixtures and PhpUnit context

This is my fixture's Class, as you can see i inject UserPasswordEncoderInterface in the constructor

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

/**
 * Class UserFixtures
 * @package App\DataFixtures
 */
class UserFixtures extends Fixture
{
    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $encoder;

    /**
     * UserFixtures constructor.
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder
     */
    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setFirstname('firstname1');
        $user->setLastname('lastname1');
        $user->setBalance(100);
        $user->setLastUpdateAt(new \DateTime());
        $user->setPlainPassword('test');
        $user->setOptin(true);
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $user->setEmail('user1@test.fr');
        $user->setPseudo('test');
        $user->setGender(User::GENDER_MALE);
        $user->setBirthdate((new \DateTime())->modify('-20 year'));

        $password = $this->encoder->encodePassword($user, 'test');
        $user->setPassword($password);

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

When i do :

```
bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

It's work perfectly and datas fixtures are correcty loaded in database.
I use this fixtures for my PhpUnit functionnal tests too.So i load my fixtures in my tests like this :

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$loader = new Loader();
$loader->loadFromDirectory('src/DataFixtures');
$purger = new ORMPurger();
$executor = new ORMExecutor($em, $purger);
$executor->execute($loader->getFixtures(), true);
```

But PhUnit dont understand the injection in this context and i've got this error :

```
Too few arguments to function App\DataFixtures\UserFixtures::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/psylo/Projects/api-pmu/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Loader.php on line 193 and exactly 1 expected in /home/psylo/Projects/api-pmu/src/DataFixtures/UserFixtures.php:25
```

So how can i specify injection in phpunit tests Doctrine fixtures load ? 
There is an other solution to do that ?

Thx in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bash file like this (I call it usually `runtests.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load 
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

After you can launch from you CLI:

```
./runtests.sh
```

P.S. I don't know exactly how do you launch test into your application I have suppose in this way: `./vendor/bin/phpunit`